# scala: if flatMap is used to apply flatten after a map function why flatMap returns IndexedSeq[List[(Char,Int)]] while map give IndexedSeq[(Char,Int)]

Tags: scala

I am trying to understand the below piece of code using flatMap and map. Please explain as why flatMap returns IndexedSeq[List[(Char,Int)]]:

**Using `flatMap`:**

```
def combinations(
    occurrencesV: List[(Char, Int)]): IndexedSeq[List[(Char, Int)]] = {
  val ind = for {
    occ <- occurrencesV
    x <- (occ._2 to 1 by -1)
  } yield (occ._1, x)
  (1 to 2).flatMap(ind.combinations)
}

combinations(List(('a', 2), ('e', 1), ('t', 2)))
```

**Using `map`:**

```
def comT(occurrencesV: List[(Char, Int)]): IndexedSeq[(Char, Int)] = {
  val ind = for {
    occ <- occurrencesV
    x <- (occ._2 to 1 by -1)
  } yield (occ._1, x)
  (1 to 2).map(ind)
}

comT(List(('a', 2), ('e', 1), ('t', 2)))
```

I understand that IndexedSeq is because of Range but then why List[(Char,Int)]?

Answer (score 0):

In `def combinations`, `ind` is a `List[(Char, Int)]`.

`ind.combinations`, passed to `flatMap`, produces a `List[List[(Char, Int)]]`. `flatMap` unwraps the first list level, but not the second, which is returned in the result.

Answer (score 0):

> > why flatMap returns IndexedSeq[List[(Char,Int)]] while map give IndexedSeq[(Char,Int)]

Thats because you are using `ind.combinations` in the `flatMap` and only using `ind` in `map`

`ind.combinations` would give you *all the combinations* of `ind` as a `List`.

*You are passing different functions to flatMap and map*. Try passing the same functions and you will see that `flatMap is used to apply flatten after a map function`

You will see that if you pass `ind.combinations` in the `map` function of your `comT` function, it will return `IndexedSeq[Iterator[List[(Char,Int)]]]`

```
def comT(occurrencesV: List[(Char, Int)]): IndexedSeq[Iterator[List[(Char,Int)]]] = {
  val ind = for {occ <- occurrencesV
                 x <- (occ._2 to 1 by -1)
  } yield (occ._1,x)
  (1 to 2).map(ind.combinations)
}
```

**The `Iterator` is *flattened in your first combinations function* by `flatMap`**

I hope the explanation is clear and understandable